# placeholder text for chosen plugin for single select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I have the chosen plugin for single select implemented in my code. I am trying to add the Placeholder text for the search boxes but I am not able to. I have tried the following things:

```
<select id="search_pi" name="search_pi" type="text" class="chosen-select"
        style="width:450px;" onchange="this.form.submit()" >

  <option value="">Search Project/Initiative...</option>
  <?php
    include "../includes/search_dropdown.php";
    foreach($proj_ini_Array as $qa){
      echo "<option value = \"$qa\">$qa</option>";
    }
  ?>
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen({
      placeholder_text_single: "Select an option",
      no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });  
  });
</script>
```

In the select field, I also tried using `data-placeholder="Select an option"` but that does not help too. Can someone please let me know what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Placeholder text? Do you mean just adding a `disabled` attribute on the first `<option>` tag that just provides information, so it cannot be picked on the dropdown?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The highlighted text in the form box.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Okay. I found out the answer. We need to have the first option as blank for the placeholder text to be activated for Single select search box.

```
<select id="search_pi" name="search_pi" type="text" class="chosen-select" style="width:450px;" onchange="this.form.submit()" >

  <option> </option>
  <?php
    include "../includes/search_dropdown.php";
    foreach($proj_ini_Array as $qa){
      echo "<option value = \"$qa\">$qa</option>";
    }
  ?>
```

In the above case, placeholder text will default to "Select an option".

For a customized placeholder-text for a single search select box you can edit your js file as below and have the first option blank for the placeholder text to be displayed:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen({
      placeholder_text_single: "Select Project/Initiative...",
      no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });  
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 39):

use `data-placeholder="YOUR TEXT"` in `select` tag

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! its straight to the point and easier to configure!

Answer (score 6):

To make your first option simply a guidance text, but unable for users to select it, use this:

```
<option selected="selected" disabled>Search Project/Initiative...</option>
```

*** Edit ***

Ah sorry, didn't read your question clearly enough to begin with.

Apparently the first `<option>` needs to be an empty one. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CmEt2/).

Comment: That definitely sounds like an option...but I would prefer using the Placeholder text functionality which chosen offers. Check out this link http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html

Comment: @tOmppa- I figured that out :) But I could not answer my own question :(. We would not have to keep the first option blank for a multiple select box.

Comment: You can answer it after a day has passed, i believe.

Answer (score 2):

User response  @Zack Joerdan solved my problem.
So the spring required value inside option

```
<select placeholder="Placeholder goes here">
    <option value=""><!-- Empty option goes here. --><option>
    <option>Other Option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a better/easier solution to this problem if you are constructing via HTML rather than JS. You have to do two things.

1. The first `<option>` in your `<select>` should be empty.
2. You should include `placeholder="Placeholder goes here"` in your `<select>`. Apparently this was once called `data-placeholder`, which I think has led to some confusion.

So, in total:

```
<select placeholder="Placeholder goes here">
    <option><!-- Empty option goes here. --><option>
    <option>Other Option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply add `data-placeholder="YOUR TEXT"` No need to use jquery for the same

**Here is the example**

```
<select id="search_pi"  data-placeholder="Select Project/Initiative..." name="search_pi" type="text" class="chosen-select" style="width:450px;" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
              <?php
                include "../includes/search_dropdown.php";
                foreach($proj_ini_Array as $qa){
                  echo "<option value = \"$qa\">$qa</option>";
                }
              ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <select data-placeholder="Select language" class="chosen-select">
            <option></option>
            <option>English</option>
            <option>Urdu</option>
            <option>Hindi</option>
            <option>Chinese</option>
        </select>
```

Add data-placeholder attribute on select and make sure first option is empty.