# Placeholder text in chosen plugin for multiple select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I'm working with a chosen multiple select. I'm trying to add a placeholder text for the select with `data-placeholder` attribute, but it doesn't fully work.

The placeholder appears only after a click is performed on the select input and then out of it.

I tried to put an empty option in the select as suggested for single selects in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200638/placeholder-text-for-chosen-plugin-for-single-select-not-working), but it didn't work.

Does anybody have a solution?

Here is my code

```
<select id="mySelect" data-placeholder="Choose an option ..." class="chosen-select allow_additem item_to_upper" multiple tabindex="4">
</select>
```

The select is filled with javascript.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle ? https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't post your code it is hard to guess the answer. But if you want a "placeholder" to be displayed in your dropdown menu there is a simlpe way to achieve this. Just add an option with selected disabled<s>. That way you obviously can't select this option but it will be displayed as first element.</s> + style to hide it ;)

```html
<select>
  <option selected disabled style="display:none">Chose your destiny</option>
  <option value="1">Happiness</option>
  <option value="2">Glory</option>
  <option value="3">Wisdom</option>
</select>
```

---

EDIT: added `style="display:none"`

I know it's little cheated and may not be the perfect solution but it does the trick. I haven't used `data-placeholder`, so I don't know how to use it to solve your problem, but I hope this gives a desired alternative for you.

Comment: I don't really want to have the placeholder as an option. When clicking on the select I want the place holder to disappear and the list to be shown.

Comment: I edited the answer to better fit your requirements.

Comment: If it were a simple select element it would be perfect. But it's not. I'm using chosen plugin for the multiple select element. So the rendering is completely different when I apply the solution you suggested.

Comment: If you could make a code example on jsfiddle it would be easier to help you. Do you see any errors in your console. Maybe double check your class attribute... Could you provide additional information?

Answer (score 0):

This is a chosen project bug. When you instantiate an element chosen, this creates an structure in your DOM like this:

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 100%;" title="" id="mySelect_chosen">
  <ul class="chosen-choices">
    <li class="search-field">
      <input type="text" value="Choose an option ..." class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 90px;" tabindex="-1">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="chosen-drop">
    <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

the placeholder was put into input value, with fixed width 90px. To work around this problem I suggest you to put this into your css assets:

```
li.search-field input.default {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with

```
li.search-field input.default {
  width: 100% !important;
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is @Josep's Answer + these lines

```
    .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-field{
        width: 100%;
    }
```